# How to add a column to a dataframe from another dataframe in Pandas but similar to a left join in SQL and change at the same time the column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframes df1 and df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A1kT23', '4523', 'B333', '49O33'],
'Name': ['Example A', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test123'],
'Debt_Equity': [-65.56, 0.55, 0, 37],
 'EV_Sales': [9.28, 0.53, 11.3, 45]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['123', '4523', 'B333', '789'],
'Name': ['Example 123', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test789'],
'Country': ['USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Turkey'],
 'Sector': ['IT', 'Materials', 'Communication', 'IT']})
```

I would love to make something similar like a left join in SQL with adding only the column ISIN of df2 to df1, but ISIN of df2 shall get the column name 'Bestand', so that I get the following result df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A1kT23', '4523', 'B333', '49O33'],
'Name': ['Example A', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test123'],
'Debt_Equity': [-65.56, 0.55, 0, 37],
 'EV_Sales': [9.28, 0.53, 11.3, 45],
 'Bestand': ['', '4523', 'B333', '']})
```

I tried it with the merge function but somehow I wasn't very successful:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['ISIN']], on=["ISIN"],  how="left")
```

How can I create df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Bestand"] = np.where(df1.ISIN.isin(df2.ISIN), df1.ISIN, "")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     ISIN       Name  Debt_Equity  EV_Sales Bestand
0  A1kT23  Example A       -65.56      9.28        
1    4523    Name Xy         0.55      0.53    4523
2    B333  Example B         0.00     11.30    B333
3   49O33    Test123        37.00     45.00
```

Comment: Ty, that was exactly,, what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to duplicate your 'ISIN' column, calling it 'Bestand', and then merging with just those two columns:

```
df2['Bestand'] = df2['ISIN']
df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['ISIN', 'Bestand']], on=["ISIN"], how='left')
```

You can cleanup NaNs with `fillna('')` if you want.

Comment: Ty, looks good, but somehow in a bigger dataframe it delivers somehow more lines than before.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to join lines with the same names, to add `df2.ISIN` as `df.Bestand`

- To change the name to `Bestand`, you’ll need to rename it before merging
- `ISIN` is not your merge condition in this case, `Name` is

```
>>> df = df1.merge(df2[['ISIN', 'Name']].rename(columns={'ISIN': 'Bestand'}), on='Name', how='left')
>>> df
     ISIN       Name  Debt_Equity  EV_Sales Bestand
0  A1kT23  Example A       -65.56      9.28     NaN
1    4523    Name Xy         0.55      0.53    4523
2    B333  Example B         0.00     11.30    B333
3   49O33    Test123        37.00     45.00     NaN
```

Here, `how='left'` specifies that when rows are missing on the right, we do not remove the rows from the left.
Missing values are `NaN`, by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding left_on and right_on instead of only on in the merge function.